# Arrays (Search for Highest Value)

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble with the last "for" loop. The code cannot run because of that "for" loop. I am trying to find the highest price item and then I am trying to output that price to the user. Before this, the user had to output the price. The "i" in both prices in the "if" statement seem to not work well.

double highest = prices [0];

```
    for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i ++);
    {
            if(prices[i] > highest)
                highest = prices[i];
    }
```

Full Code below
{
        //Arrays

```
    String [] daysOfTheWeek = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
    String [] foods = new String [5];
    double [] prices = new double [5];

    //What is being served?

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



    for (int i = 0; i < daysOfTheWeek.length; i ++ )
        {
         System.out.println("What entree is being served on " + daysOfTheWeek[i]);

         foods[i] = keyboard.nextLine();

        }
    for (int i = 0; i < foods.length; i ++)
        {
        System.out.println("What is the price on " + foods[i]);

        prices[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }

    double highest = prices [0];

    for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i ++);
    {
            if(prices[i] > highest)
                highest = prices[i];
    }

}
```

}

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i ++);remove ; from for loop.

Comment: Oh wow, that one minor mistakes. Thanks all for helping me with that.

Comment: The semicolon afterward the for loop statement means that your for loop is effectively doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a `;` after the for statement:

```
for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i ++);
{
        if(prices[i] > highest)
            highest = prices[i];
}
```

Make it this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i ++)
{
        if(prices[i] > highest)
            highest = prices[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi colon from

```
for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i ++);
```

What you have written has the following effect :

```
    for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i ++){
        //do nothing
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your for loop.  You do one thing

```
for(int i = 0; i < prices.length; i ++)
{
        if(prices[i] > highest)
            highest = prices[i];
}
```

for loop should be continue here upto (prices.length-1).
It will help you definately in both for loops. Because loop starts from the 0 in arrays.